# sed - replace patterns with spaces on OS X

Tags: macos, sed

I have a bunch of text files (named `install*`) in which I need to replace the expression `curl -L` with the expression `curl -k -L`. I am on OS X 10, Yosemite.

The following attempts don't work:

```
sed -e  "s/'curl -L'/'curl -k -L'/g" install*

sed -i '' -e "s/'curl -L'/'curl -k -L'/g" install*
```

The contents of the files are shown (as if I had typed `cat`), but replacement isn't performed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that **you're nesting quoting mechanisms (delimiters) when you shouldn't**.

Generally, you should **use *single* quotes to enclose an `sed` script *as a whole***:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/curl -L/curl -k -L/g' install*
```

By using *single* quotes, the script is protected from accidental interpretation by the *shell*.
<sup>If you do want the shell to interpret parts of a `sed` script *beforehand*, *splice those parts in* as *double*-quoted strings.</sup>

To `sed`'s `s` function, it is `/` that acts as the delimiter - no *additional* quoting of the strings between `/` instances should be used, and your use of `'` simply causes `sed` to consider these single quotes *part of the regex to match / the replacement string*. (As an aside: you're free to choose a delimiter other than `/`).

That said, if you do need to force interpretation of certain characters as *literals*, **use `\`-escaping**, such as using `\.` in the regex to represent a *literal* `.`
This is **the *only* quoting mechanism that `sed` itself supports**.

However, **in your particular case, neither the string used in the regex nor the string used as the replacement string need escaping**.

For a **generic way to escape strings for use as literals in these situations**, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for the functional example and specially for the thorough explanation. I learned a lot from this answer.

Comment: @thiagoveloso: My pleasure; I'm glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You need `-i`.

GNU sed uses `-i` without arguments to mean "replace in-place".

BSD sed needs an empty argument, so you'll have to use `sed -i '' -e '...' install*`

There's no portable way to do it with sed...

Comment: It runs but still doesn't affect the files. I have edited the question to reflect this extra attempt.

Comment: Good pointer re difference between GNU and BSD sed, but `-i` by itself - _with our without option-argument_ - means "update in place" - the option-_argument_ simply specifies a suffix (filename extension) to apped to a _backup_ of the original file. Since GNU `sed` considers this option-argument _optional_, `-i` is sufficient to say "create no backup file", whereas BSD `sed` considers the option-argument _mandatory_, so `-i ''` must be used to express the same thing.